# parallel arrows in pb-diagram

Tags: diagrams, arrows

It is possible to get two parallel maps (one pointing to the left, the other to the right) between two nodes using `pb-diagram`? I know it can be done with TikZ, and maybe with some other package, but I use `pb-diagram`. Note that the option `=` is not enough. I would like to have also the heads of the arrows (the `=` option just draws two parallel lines)...

Answer (score 3):

The style file `pb-diagram.sty` contains a couple of examples of custom arrows.  Basically you have to build an appropriate representation using LaTeX's built-in `picture` environment.  Here is an attempt at this.  The separation of the two arrows is controlled by `\twoarrowsep`.  If you do not need the diagonal arrows, a smaller value may look better.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\newcount\twoarrowsep
\twoarrowsep=50

\makeatletter
\@namedef{dgo@dd}{\let\dg@VECTOR=\dg@twoarrowedvector}%

\newcount\dg@XSHIFT
\newcount\dg@YSHIFT
\def\dg@twoarrowedvector(#1,#2)#3{%
   \begingroup
   \dg@XTEMP=#1\relax\multiply\dg@XTEMP\m@ne\relax
   \dg@YTEMP=#2\relax\multiply\dg@YTEMP\m@ne\relax
   \dg@ZTEMP=#1\relax
   \ifnum\dg@ZTEMP<\z@
     \multiply\dg@ZTEMP\m@ne\relax \fi
   \ifnum\dg@YTEMP<\z@
     \advance\dg@ZTEMP by -\dg@YTEMP
   \else \advance\dg@ZTEMP by \dg@YTEMP \fi
   \dg@XSHIFT=#2\relax\multiply\dg@XSHIFT\m@ne\relax\multiply\dg@XSHIFT\twoarrowsep\relax
     \divide\dg@XSHIFT by \dg@ZTEMP\relax
   \dg@YSHIFT=#1\relax\multiply\dg@YSHIFT\twoarrowsep\relax\divide\dg@YSHIFT by \dg@ZTEMP\relax
   \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \thinlines
      \put(-\dg@XSHIFT,-\dg@YSHIFT){\vector(#1,#2){#3}}%
      \put(\dg@XSHIFT,\dg@YSHIFT){\line(#1,#2){#3}}%
      \put(\dg@XSHIFT,\dg@YSHIFT){\vector(\dg@XTEMP,\dg@YTEMP){0}}
   \end{picture}%
   \endgroup}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{diagram}
    \node{A}
    \arrow{e,dd}
    \arrow{se,dd}
    \arrow{s,dd}
    \node{B}\\
    \node{C} \node{D} \arrow{w,dd} \arrow{n,dd}
  \end{diagram}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

The code draws two arrows shifted away from the standard axis by equal amounts in a perpendicular direction.  The opposite arrow is actually drawn in two parts, the stem and the head, to avoid some extra calculations.  So the `picture` environment consits of three `\put` commands.

As in the package itself I have kept to the standard arithmetic operators provided by LaTeX; some other package may give you access to a square root operator, and so could give better adjust ment of the spacing for sloping arrows.