# dotted arrow with pb-diagram

Tags: packages

Moreover, it is possible to get two parallel maps (one pointing to the left, the other to the right and **shaft option being dotted or dashed arrow** ) between two nodes using pb-diagram?
This question is related to: [double arrow with pb-diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85051/parallel-arrows-in-pb-diagram)
.Thank you!

Comment: Would you be willing to use another package such as [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd)?

Comment: Yes, of course...I read the tik-cd documentation and is very useful, everyone told me it is hard to draw diagrams but it seems no one tried to do it...I will play with a little bit and if i fail, i will come back to ask a question...

Comment: It's not hard at all and it is very powerful. I've provided a simple example below.

Answer (score 4):

The more modern and powerful [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package offers you dashed or dotted arrows and an easy mechanism to shift them if required. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A\arrow[r,shift left=1ex,dotted]{}{f}\ar{d} 
  & B\arrow[l,shift left=0.5ex,dashed]{}{g} 
\\
C\arrow[r,shift left=1ex,dashed,blue]{}{k} 
  & D\arrow[l,shift left=0.5ex,dashed,densely dotted,red]{}{l}\ar{u}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An attempt

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{commutative diagrams/.cd, arrow style=tikz,diagrams={>= triangle 45}}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm,column sep=3cm,inner sep=3ex]
A       \arrow[thick,rightarrow,yshift=1ex,]{r}{}        
        \arrow[thick,leftarrow,xshift=1ex]{d}
        \arrow[thick,rightarrow,
                start anchor={[yshift=-1.5ex]},
                end anchor={[xshift=-1.5ex]}]{dr}{} 
& B     \arrow[thick,rightarrow,yshift=-1ex]{l}{} 
        \arrow[thick,rightarrow,xshift=-1ex]{d}{} \\
C       \arrow[thick,leftarrow,xshift=-1ex]{u}{}   
        \arrow[thick,leftarrow,yshift=1ex]{r}{}        
& D     \arrow[thick,leftarrow,yshift=-1ex]{l}{}         
        \arrow[thick,rightarrow,xshift=1ex]{u}{} 
        \arrow[thick,rightarrow,
               start anchor={[yshift=1.5ex]},
               end anchor={[xshift=1.5ex]}]{ul}{} 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this answer should be transferred to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85051 Thank you!